# non asp.net resources authetication and authorization in iis6

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I'm creating a website which besides other tasks will play some recorded files. these recorded files are on a remote server with private ip address, so I've created a virtual directory which points to a share directory on the mentioned server. 
now I'm able to playback the files using client side controls like wmplayer. BUT the problem is sound file urls are accessible without any authentication and authorization.
is there anyway to enforce .net authorization and authentication (in web.config) on this virtual directory? I also should mention I can not use solutions like httphandlers to download the files because file are streamed using iis so user could navigate on the file without downloading all of it)
thanx

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS (I suppose you use IIS7.0 or later). Find the mentioned virtual directory and click on it. In the listed features find Authentication, right click on it and press Open Feature. Then disable anonymous authentication for this folder. Does the problem persist?

Comment: I'm using iis 6. I've tested what u said but I don't want the user pass popup show and get credentials. I'm using forms authentication and Roles to control access to my aspx files I want the same apply on the shared folder
thax